# BLKID not giving output in linux when run in file

Tags: linux, bash, outputstream

I've written following script in linux to get USB detail: this script is executed from udev when usb is attached.

```
    fgrep -A 15 'New USB device found' /var/log/messages | tail -n 16 > usb_detail
    SERIAL=$(sed -n '5s/A.*: //p' usb_detail)
    SIZE=$(sed -n '10s/A.*: //p' usb_detail)
    MOUNT=$(sed -n '14s/A.*: //p' usb_detail)
    blkid > Label
    LABEL=$(grep $MOUNT Label | awk '{print $2}')
```

Now problem is that I'm getting all values (Serial No, Size, Mount on) but when it goes to check lable of usb from BLKID then i get nothing. this command gives me nothing in output:

```
blkid > Label
```

this command is working properly in command prompt. but when i run it in this script (which is called from UDEV when usb is attached) then it doesn't give any output.

So how can i figure out that what is main problem and why I'm not getting anything in LABEL file?

Here is my /var/log/messages:

```
Apr 28 08:25:58 box2 kernel: usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0411, idProduct=0105
Apr 28 08:25:58 box2 kernel: usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
Apr 28 08:25:58 box2 kernel: usb 1-3: Product: USB-SATA Bridge
Apr 28 08:25:58 box2 kernel: usb 1-3: Manufacturer: BUFFALO
Apr 28 08:25:58 box2 kernel: usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 00001412AA38
Apr 28 08:25:58 box2 kernel: usb 1-3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Apr 28 08:25:58 box2 kernel: scsi25 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
Apr 28 08:26:05 box2 kernel: scsi 25:0:0:0: Direct-Access     BUFFALO  External HDD          PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
Apr 28 08:26:05 box2 kernel: sd 25:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Apr 28 08:26:05 box2 kernel: sd 25:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
Apr 28 08:26:05 box2 kernel: sd 25:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Apr 28 08:26:05 box2 kernel: sd 25:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Apr 28 08:26:05 box2 kernel: sd 25:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Apr 28 08:26:05 box2 kernel: sda: sda1
Apr 28 08:26:05 box2 kernel: sd 25:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Apr 28 08:26:05 box2 kernel: sd 25:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

and here is blkid output from command prompt:

```
[root@box2 usbmon]# blkid
/dev/sdf1: UUID="2d1bd58e-86ea-4ab2-99e3-ec2d1fb24021" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdf2: UUID="Je95wE-NW7f-Mqlv-UBgi-qNOL-8i35-8cUUTj" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/vg_box2-lv_root: UUID="27cf24f7-4e7d-42bd-97be-09ddc6eb614b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/vg_box2-lv_swap: UUID="36c54ea3-f9f3-455a-9c84-58e7317d1e60" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/mapper/vg_box2-lv_home: UUID="5cac0192-2757-4cf6-b70f-d9ff8fbe6f36" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda1: LABEL="BU5" UUID="242DB177461FD69A" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Comment: In the end, hat are you trying to acheive? During udev hot plug, a block device has not yet been created in `/dev`, so `blkid` won't find it. You also do not need to look at the system log since the appropriate information is passed via environment variables to udev scripts that point to lots of information about the drive in `/sys`.

Comment: I'm trying to email usb size, lable and Mount on, when a usb is attached/removed from usb port. As i dont know how to get these values form udev env thats why i used this way. if you can tell me then i would be thankful to you. i cudn't find it when i googled. even i posted a question here on this forum but no response.

Comment: You can see all the variables set using `printenv` and then use the paths provided to look around in `/sys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed the issue by changing syntax

```
blkid > Label
```

to

```
/sbin/blkid > Label
```

dont know why but sometimes it works.

Answer (score 6):

Running with sudo will give you proper out.

```
sudo blkid
```